# How can i convert varchar to date format

Tags: sql

Code seems correct still getting error message

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
UPDATE G
SET 
QuoteDate = FORMAT (DATEADD(yy,4,CAST(M.PaymentDate as date)),'MM/dd/yyyy')
FROM  dbo.Grantor G    
INNER JOIN  dbo.Member M ON G.Quoteid = M.fQuoteid
```

Data Types of fields are as below

```
QuoteDate    --->     DATE , 
PaymentDate  --->     VARCHAR
```

Please correct me if I am doing wrong.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: "PaymentDate  --->     VARCHAR" There's the root of your problem. Don't store dates as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your `M.PaymentDate` values is probably failing to cast to a date, so it is not running and will throw an error. You can double check if your dates are good with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT 
M.PaymentDate, 
TRY_CAST(M.PaymentDate AS date)
FROM dbo.Member m


WHERE TRY_CAST(M.PaymentDate AS date) IS NULL
```

The next step is up to you. You can either parse the bad values somehow, or exclude them.

Comment: Thanks @dfundako ..it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using conversion at all?  If the columns are stored as date/times, then this is not necessary:

```
UPDATE G            
    SET QuoteDate = DATEADD(year, 4, CAST(M.PaymentDate as date))
    FROM dbo.Grantor G JOIN  
         dbo.Member M     
        ON G.Quoteid = M.fQuoteid ;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the earliest response. i tried this code unfortunately still getting the same error message